# Join depending on a second non related join, doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm working in a query builder, the intent is to return a ranking of payments of resellers. Resellers relates with its clients through a non foreign key column (affiliateCode), so I need to relate this join with a list of entities that depends upon this non-key join.

The result I end up like this but its not working. Although no error is thrown.

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder->select('SUM(pay.value) as total_points, cli.id as client_id')
        ->from('Application\Model\Payment', 'pay')
        ->innerJoin('pay.subscription', 'sub')
        ->innerJoin('sub.client', 'representative')
        ->innerJoin(
            'representative.userCollection',
            'seller',
            'WITH',
            'seller.affiliateCode = cli.affiliateCode'
        )
        ->innerJoin('seller.clientCollection', 'cli')
        ->where(
            '
                pay.status = :donePaymentStatus
                AND representative.affiliateCode IS NOT NULL
            '
        )
        ->groupBY('cli.id')
        ->orderBY('total_points', 'DESC');

    $queryBuilder->setParameters([
        'donePaymentStatus' => PaymentStatus::DONE,
    ]);
```

If what I'm trying to do is not possible through joins, can you suggest an alternative. Maybe nested queries.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting an error is that your syntax is fine, but your logic is faulty.  An INNER JOIN is the most exclusive join you can perform - it will return ONLY the records which match ALL conditions.  You're likely to have more luck with less exclusive joins (LEFT or RIGHT JOIN).

Venn Diagrams help:

http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: If I change for the inner join with a non foreign key for a left join I get the result but the cli entity is missing. Maybe doctrine is getting crazy with ``representative.userCollection`` because it has alrealy a foreign key and I'm trying to use other 'non relation' instead ?

Comment: Have you tried taking it out of the hands of the query builder and writing it up as a DQL query instead?  Might highlight an issue or two.